# Finding the coordinates of the point on the graph of $f(x) = (x+1)(x+2)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Im trying to find the coordinates of the point on the graph of $f(x) = (x+1)(x+2)$ at which the tangent is parallel to the line with the equation $3x - y - 1 = 0$

How do i find the coordinates?

What I've tried is:

Since it is parallel, i know the slope is: $3$

So I found the derivative of $f(x) = (x+1)(x+2)$ and set it equal to $3$.

So $2x + 3 = 3$ which will then be equal to $0$

So, I got the $x$ coordinate as $0$ and when i substitute $0$ into the original equation i get $2$.

So are the coordinates $(0,2)$ right? or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks perfect. Great job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice work! You are correct, your reasoning, and your approach to the problem are "spot on."

(Thanks for showing your work. It helps us check things over. More important than the "final answer" are the reasoning and the methods used to get it.)

Comment: It is great to validate the OP's work +1